# Vue nested route

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I have the following route from my vue app. Where I've created a nested route.

With the following code I'm not able to see the contents of my children route `/admin/create-post`

When I vist the route `/admin/create-post` the content of it's parent route `/admin` is shown

```js
const routes = [
    {
        path: '/',
        name: 'Home',
        component: () => import('../views/Home')
    },
    {
        path: '/admin', component: () => import('../views/auth/Dashboard'),
        name: 'Dashboard',
        children: [
            {
                path: 'create-post',
                component: () => import('../views/auth/PostEdit'),
                name: 'Create Post'
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        path: '*',
        component: () => import('../views/error/404')
    }
]
```

Working demo: [Code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-architecture-ombqm)

Comment: Can you create a codepen to see the code structure of your project?

Comment: Question updated